# Using DISTINCT does not work in the sql query

Tags: sql, distinct

I have a following relationship.[image: Database Relationship]

and this is my query:

```
 sql = "SELECT DISTINCT g.ExeName, d.FileRec, d.RefDes, d.Title as [Component Title],
       c.Title AS [Sheet Title], f.FileName, f.Title AS [Sim Schematic Title] FROM
       (((((((Projects AS a INNER JOIN ProjectFile AS b ON a.RecNo=b.ProjectRec) 
       INNER JOIN Files AS c ON b.FileRec=c.RecNo) 
       INNER JOIN Components AS d ON c.RecNo=d.FileRec) 
       INNER JOIN CompP2Sim AS e ON d.RecNo=e.CompRec) 
       INNER JOIN p2Sim AS f ON e.p2SimRec=f.RecNo) 
       INNER JOIN ExeTable g ON f.ExeRec=g.RecNo) 
       INNER JOIN EffecP2Sim AS h ON f.RecNo=h.p2SimRec)
       WHERE d.StandardRec = " + b.Tag + " and a.RecNo = " + cbModel.SelectedValue + "
       AND c.SystemRec = " + (int)systemMode + 
       " AND d.RecNo IN (SELECT DISTINCT CompRec from CompP2Sim) AND h.ModelRec = " + cbModel.SelectedValue + " order by d.refdes";
```

But with this query I still get duplicates. How i can make the P2Sim's RecNo to be DISTINCT.

This is the result:

[image]

It is duplicating the same result, I want to just get the result with no p2sim RecNo duplicated. In this result, the file rec is different but they both have the same P2Sim's RecNo. I tried to group the query but I can't. I get an error every time I try to run it. "RefDes column can't be fined." It doesn't matter where I want to put the () to group the Distinct I get that error.

Comment: `FileRec` is distinct, its values being 1 and 3.  If you remove `FileRec` you'll get only one value for `component title` and `sim schematic title`

Comment: I deleted the FileRec from Select part but I still get 2 results. it should be a way to just make the p2sim's RecNo to be distinct. @paqogomez

Comment: What column is different between the rows after you remove `FileRec`?

Comment: When I remove FileRec it just doesn't display the fileRec in the result. the rest of the columns are the same. the only way to avoid duplicates is to make the P2Sim's RecNo to be distict.@paqogomez

Comment: This is your problem, you cannot "group" distinct.  Putting parens around your query will help in your where clause, but not in the results.

Comment: Head over to SQLFiddle.com and put together a sample schema.  Duplicate your problem there.  Then it will be trivial to show you how to make it better.

Answer (score 12):

`select distinct` applies to the ENTIRE row, not just a field. e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT foo, bar, baz
```

should be read more as

```
SELECT DISTINCT(foo,bar,baz)
```

and not:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(foo), NON-DISTINCT(bar), NON-DISTINCT(baz)
```

If you want a particular field to be unique within your query, then you should `group` on that field.

Comment: When I try to group my query, I get error when i run the program that the program can't find the RefDes column. I just want my P2Sim's RecNo to be Distinct but I am not getting in the Select part. I just make it to be equal to CompP2Sim's p2SimRec in Inner Join part

Comment: Oh Man! It was giving me serious trouble as why my distinct was not working. Now, it makes much more sense.